# Ineligible device iPad Air2 on Xcode 6.0?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ipad, osx-yosemite

I could't use iPad Air2 in xcode6.0 on mac with OSX 10.9.5, Xcode sorts iPad Air2 under in eligible devices category. Deployment target is iOS 8.0. Tried restarting both the device and mac, but no improvement. Any suggestions ?

But it is working in mac with Yosemite installed. Do i need to update mac with yosemite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iPad Air 2 comes with iOS 8.1, so development requires Xcode 6.1, not 6.0.

Xcode 6.1 also supports OS X Yosemite, but can be run from 10.9 (Mavericks) just as well — you don't need to update your OS, just your Xcode. (Updating to 10.10 isn't a bad idea in general, though.)

Comment: It's working fine after updating Xcode to 6.1. Thank you