# iPhone iOS 8.2 with Xcode 6.1.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, xcode6

I just updated my phone to newest iOS version (8.2) and now I have in Xcode (6.1.1) my device under Ineligible devices. I don't use Xcode beta version but I guess I should started. I just update Xcode when Store notify me but I think I should download Beta now because it fix my problem. Or is there a fix where I can run my apps in device without updating to Beta Xcode?

Comment: Have you checked it with Xcode 6.2.The final version is released.

Comment: Oh, there is update for Xcode too. I didn't notice. I'll try.

Comment: refer this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27352568/ineligible-device-ipad-air2-os-version and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613083/ios-devices-do-not-show-up-on-xcode-6-1-1-until-after-rebooting-the-mac

Comment: This is the link for Xcode 6.2 in Mac Appstore [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually this is the problem as your device has the higher OS version 8.2 which is not supported by the current Xcode version 6.1.1 you have to update your Xcode version now.

So, Now you simply update your Xcode version to the latest version of Xcode using the following [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12).

Comment: And you have to download complate 2.6GB ide just for upgrading Xcode 6.1 to 6.2. Good job Apple :)

Comment: Actually Apple should update only the required things and that how it can save amount of data to be downloaded for user and instead of downloading 2.6GB it should be done in 200 to 250MB. Hope Apple will improve their update process soon.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are upgrading Xcode to 6.2 or downgrading your phone to a version compatible with Xcode

try this: http://www.idownloadblog.com/downgrade/